# 7.1 surround sound USB headset with generic onboard sound card, do I get 7.1?

Tags: usb, audio, sound-card

So simple(ish) question, I have a laptop with a generic onboard soundcard (listed as VIA HD Audio) and I have a 7.1 surround sound usb headset.

My understanding was the soundcard had to output all the relevant channels for the headset to consume and output correctly. However I assume my default onboard sound card only has 2 channels. I am aware that some USB connection have some primitive sound card-esque chip in there which piggybacks off the CPU to do some *magic* with the audio, but I was wondering if in this setup am I actually getting 7.1 audio, or is the USB chip or Soundcard merely emulating it somehow? and if so how (at a high level, does it achieve this as it would imply that there is 0 point getting a better/external usb soundcard).

A scenario would be, I play a game which outputs audio in 5.1 with my USB headset plugged in and all audio settings are as high as are allowable.

Comment: the headset might be using its own 5.1 chipset. Knowing make/model might help

Comment: I think it is a 5.1 chipset with some pretend 7.1, I am not too fussed about the specifics of if its 5.1 or 7.1 just the fact that it is somehow creating the right channels. The actual headset in question is Plantronics GameCom 780

Comment: it has its own chip & drivers, by the look of it http://www.plantronics.com/uk/support/kb/detail.jsp?vfurl=/articles/en_GB/How_To/GameCom-780-How-to-Activate-Surround-Sound&retURL=%2Fapex%2FknowledgeSearch&region=uk&p=&c=All&k=GameCom%2B780%252F788%2B7.1%2BSurround%2BSound%2B&t=All&lang=en_GB&popup=false&c=All

Comment: So does the chip actually do the work somehow? as I was more interested in how the 2 channel soundcard can somehow become 5.1 via the usb chip... as surely the USB thing still has to use the soundcard at some point?

Comment: not necessarily, it could quite easily be its own 'sound card'. Read what the manufacturer has to say about it